# Mountain Lion!??

Tags: osx, pro-tools

Anyone remember how long it took for Avid to put out a patch for Lion?

I honestly can't believe another OS switch so soon. I guess its a new OS every year for Apple, it just seems sooner because of the press.

Is their a difficulty for Avid with this? How much does the audio driver change between OS? It would seem this would be as simple of a fix as a quick app fix.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: This was the last straw for me with OSX, I sold my iMac this week and moved to Windows full time. I'm a big gamer so there are other plusses besides the cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. With OS X there has been a a new release every year. They're extra motivated now, because they seem to be trying to merge the functionality between their computers and they're more consumer oriented devices. The company has a history of just outright changing key pieces of operational code without warning...something like that affected Sound Miner recently if memory serves. I also know a few programmers, and Apple just doesn't provide the same level of support to software developers that Microsoft does. So, be prepared for the wait.

Comment: @ShaunFarley Thanks for the update. If Apple wasn't so awesome at delivering convenience across devices/really cool apps with everything else... I would probably still be with Windows. The whole idea of letting the public generate the ideas and produce products for their hardware really opens doors for amazing stuff. But they sure do make it hard on the professional realm to like them these days.

Comment: @C3Sound - that's very true, but it does mean there are going to be more problems for professionals down the road. the consumer market is far larger than the professional, so that's the side they're going to be leaning into.

Comment: I have all sorts of software I have brought through from the days of Tiger and it keeps working in Snow Leopard. With Lion and ML Apple are further enforcing "play by the rules" code throughout. I can't help but think Avid may have been getting a bit too creative with their codebase, and don't forget Pro Tools is how many percent legacy 32 bit code? The same stuff keeps troubling Adobe. In the meantime indie developers mostly hum along happily.

Comment: @georgi.m - without a doubt. keep in mind that the base code that underlies all of the program is 15-20 years old. that doesn't make things any easier (also part of why PT11...later this year...is a complete code rewrite from the ground up). something else to keep in mind though, is that few other programs deal with rendering that amount of data in real time. few things are as simple as they seem on the exterior.

Comment: @shaun: PT11 later this year? do you have a source/link to that information... it will keep me from going to PT10 for sure.. 

Comment: @Arnoud Traa - The guys from Avid at AES this past year. PT 10 is meant to be a transitional piece of software...introduce the new plug-in formats, hardware, etc...PT 11 is going to be 64-bit (computer processing, not dynamic range). Building software that could make use of the current 64-bit CPU's required a complete code rewrite. They expect to be officially announcing at AES (though it's possible the date could slip).

Comment: @Arnoud Traa 11 being a complete code rewrite is all the more reason to upgrade to 10. Avid are preparing to pull an FCPX on everyone.. and I bet the release date will slip.

Comment: @georgi.m - the fact that they just released all the new HDX hardware says to me that they're not going to pull an FCPX. they're still adding features (many of them post-production oriented lately), not taking them away like Apple did. it is possible the date will slip, but it already has. they were originally aiming to roll out the 64-bit version this past year. so, i'm happy they're taking their time to get it right.

Comment: Wow i totally missed both answers, but thanks! 
@georgi.m: I still don't know why I should get 10 if 11 is around the corner. A. it will cost me more money (upgrades go from 9 to 11, right?) B. i don't own any hardware by Avid (I run RME hardware). If I would own a HD set I would understand, but since I don't what would be the use of upgrading to 10 first if I could just wait for 11 and save me a lot of time and some money?

Answer (score 0):

Avid has always been slow to support new iterations of the Mac OS ... It got even worse when they threw their lot in with Windows and predicted the Mac's demise. Now the Mac has survived and is thriving it's almost like they do it out of spite. Even a minor OS increment may take 6 months to a year to receive qualification as a supported configuration.

There are bugs riddled through PT that have existed on Mac since PT 6.5 and they are still there.

ie. The importing files field does not accept the spacebar as a valid input - this got worse when support for the letters "p" and "s" were also inexplicably dropped in PT 9.0 - that issue has been resolved, but the spacebar issue remains to this day. (June 2012)

AVID need a rocket up their arse.